# z3, z3py: Can I define a sort that includes a set of integers?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

This is a follow-up question of my earlier question ["Is it possible to intrinsically reduce the search space of Function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357690/z3-z3py-is-it-possible-to-intrinsically-reduce-the-search-space-of-function).

I am thinking if it is possible that I can define a sort that contains a set of integers, e.g., integers 1-10.

My intuition is that to reduce search space of Function, instead of defining a Function whose domain sort and range sort are IntSort, I want to define a Function whose domain sort and range sort are a sort that only contains a set of integers of my interest.

Suppose

Comment: do you really use operations on integers? If not, you can use datatype to define a finite enum instead of using unbounded integers?

Comment: another trick: define a wrapper function: `wrap_func(x): return sought_func(x) if 0<x<10 else return 0`.

Comment: Thanks, Ayrat. I do cast constraints on integers. Do you mean we define a Enum or DeclareSort? The problem is that the define sort is basically a set of strings rather than integers and they cannot have integers as basic elements.

Comment: Maybe I can use BitVecSort rather than IntSort to have a smaller search space.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like bit-vectors might be a good choice for modelling your problems, at least of your sets of integers are of relatively small and finite size. Z3 can handle bit-vectors combined with quantifiers and uninterpreted functions and it has some custom preprocessors for that logic so that it performs quite well for some problems; it's definitely worth a try. For details see this paper: [Efficiently Solving Quantified Bit-Vector Formulas](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10703-012-0156-2).